# Passing table row data from dialog window to main page table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is table on main page :

```
 <table>
        <th>Apple</th>
        <th>Ball</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" /><a href="#"></a></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" /><a href="#"></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is table on window dialog :

```
<table>
        <th>Apple on Dialog</th>
        <th>Ball on Dialog</th>
        <tr>
            <td>A1</td>
            <td>A2</td>
            <td>A3</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>B1</td>
            <td>B2</td>
            <td>B3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zo89a94o/), not for working code but for wanted result page,because I don't know how to create window dialog on jsfiddle so bare with my fiddle. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm not clear about what you need. Can you explain me more

Comment: see the fiddle sir, the first table I pertaining is the table on main page, notice that there is a button on each table row,when that button is clicked, I want a new window to show(which is the second table on the fiddle), and if the user will click on any row on dialog window table,the dialog will close and the tr td's  will mapped to the table row on the main page of the current index table row inpu boxes and link label.gets? :P

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zo89a94o/1/ click the button on the first table

Comment: @rogelio , yes, but If i clicked on the table row on the dialog,it will mapped backed to the current row index where the button is clicked

Comment: http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-child3-demo.php same idea on this, but on table data.

Comment: also sir, im using only the window.open(), dont want to use jquery dialog

Comment: OK, give a few minutes to make something... I will post as answer the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zo89a94o/2/)

You have to save/pass the clicked btn's identity to the dialog so that it knows where to copy and paste the content. Hope the jsfiddle gives you some idea

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#1, #2').click(function(){
        window.clickedbtnid = $(this).attr('id');
        $( "#table_dialog_1" ).dialog();
    });
    $( "#table_dialog_1" ).find('td').click(function(){
        $('#'+window.clickedbtnid).parent().prev().find('input').val($(this).text());
        $( "#table_dialog_1" ).dialog('close');
    })
});
```

Comment: `$('#input_'+id).attr('value', $(this).html());` this was closed to what i want the first td table of dialog window to pass on input, and second td and third on link area. see my last table on my fiddle please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a click event for buttons on the first table and assign the `TD` text to the input on the same row of the button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#1, #2').on('click', function(){
        $("#table_dialog_1").dialog();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#table_dialog_1 td').unbind('click').on('click', function(){
            console.log('#input_'+id);
            $('#input_'+id).attr('value', $(this).html());
            $('#table_dialog_1').dialog('close');
        });
    });
});
```

I `unbind` the click event inside on the first click event to remove previous events.

See the complete [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zo89a94o/3/)

If you need to work with popup instead of dialog, follow this [simple tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-value-from-child-popup-window-to-parent-page-window-using-JavaScript.aspx)

**UPDATE**

In order to use `window.open()`, in the parent window put this javascript code:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function(){
    clickedButton = this;
    $( "#table_dialog_1" ).dialog();
    window.button_clicked_id = $(this).attr('id');  
});
```

And this code in the child window.

```
var the_button = window.opener.button_clicked_id;
var clickedButton = $('#'+the_button, window.opener.document);
$( '#table_dialog_1 tr').click(function(){
    var  tds = $(this).children();
    $(clickedButton).parent().prev().find('input').val(tds.eq(0).html());
    $(clickedButton).next('a').text(tds.eq(2).html()+','+tds.eq(1).html());
    $( "#table_dialog_1" ).dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: $('#input_'+id).attr('value', $(this).html()); this was closed to what i want the first td table of dialog window to pass on input, and second td and third on link area. see my last table on my fiddle please

Comment: can you explain me again please? I don't understand what you want with the comment :D.

Comment: not yet sir, On the fiddle it is using jquery ui dialog with table,I cant work it on using window.open() where my table is located